# Encountering an UseMethod("predict") error when trying to run 'predict; command in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to run a SIS(Sure Independence screening)-SCAD model on a high-dimensional dataset. My goal is to measure a confusion matrix and then calculate these following metrics - accuracy, sensitivity, specificity and F1 score.

However, when I am trying to use the 'predict' function I am getting the following error:

```
model_prediction <- predict(model,X_test,type="response")
```

> Error in UseMethod("predict") :
> no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

I do not understand this.

The details of the SIS package is given [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SIS/SIS.pdf).

This is the code I am running:

```
rm(list = ls())

#Installing necessary libraries
library(HiDimDA) #this is where the high-dimensional data is stored
library(SIS)
library(caTools)

data("AlonDS")
set.seed(123)  # Set seed for reproducibility

split <- sample.split(AlonDS$grouping, SplitRatio = 0.8)

train_data <- subset(AlonDS, split == TRUE)
test_data <- subset(AlonDS, split == FALSE)

# Extracting predictor variables and grouping variable
X_train <- train_data[, -(1:6)]  # Exclude non-predictor columns
y_train <- train_data$grouping

X_test <- test_data[, -(1:6)]  # Exclude non-predictor columns
y_test <- test_data$grouping

# Convert grouping variable to factor
y_train <- as.factor(y_train)
y_test <- as.factor(y_test)

# Check the structure of X_train
str(X_train)

# Check the structure of y_train
str(y_train)

# Set greedy to FALSE
greedy <- FALSE

# Standardize the features
X_train_matrix <- scale(X_train)

# Convert grouping variable to numeric (0 and 1)
y_train_numeric <- as.numeric(y_train) - 1

# SIS-SCAD with the full training set
model <- SIS(X_train_matrix, 
             y_train_numeric,
             family = "binomial",
             penalty = "MCP",
             concavity.parameter = 3,
             tune = "bic",
             nfolds = 10,
             type.measure = "deviance",
             gamma.ebic = 1,
             nsis = NULL,
             iter = TRUE,
             iter.max = ifelse(greedy == FALSE, 10, 
                               floor(nrow(X_train_matrix) / log(nrow(X_train_matrix)))), 
             varISIS = "vanilla", 
             perm = FALSE, 
             greedy = FALSE, 
             greedy.size = 1, 
             seed = NULL, 
             standardize = TRUE) 

# Making predictions
model_prediction <- predict(model,X_test,type="response")

# Convert predicted probabilities to class labels
predictions_class <- ifelse(predictions_prob > 0.5, "healthy", "colonc")

# Assuming you have the true labels for comparison
true_labels <- as.character(y_test)

# Convert predictions_class and true_labels to factors with the same levels
predictions_class <- factor(predictions_class, levels = c("healthy", "colonc"))
true_labels <- factor(true_labels, levels = c("healthy", "colonc"))

# Check the levels of predicted and true labels
levels(predictions_class)
levels(true_labels)

# Create a confusion matrix
conf_matrix <- confusionMatrix(predictions_class, true_labels)

# Extract values from the confusion matrix
conf_matrix_values <- as.table(conf_matrix)

# Calculate accuracy
accuracy <- sum(diag(conf_matrix_values)) / sum(conf_matrix_values)
cat("Accuracy:", accuracy, "\n")

# Calculate sensitivity (recall)
sensitivity <- conf_matrix_values[2, 2] / sum(conf_matrix_values[2, ])
cat("Sensitivity (Recall):", sensitivity, "\n")

# Calculate specificity
specificity <- conf_matrix_values[1, 1] / sum(conf_matrix_values[1, ])
cat("Specificity:", specificity, "\n")

# Calculate F1 score
precision <- conf_matrix_values[2, 2] / sum(conf_matrix_values[, 2])
recall <- sensitivity
f1_score <- 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)
cat("F1 Score:", f1_score, "\n")
```